# Automatic differentiation paper: need help understanding syntax.

Tags: derivatives, functors

In [this](http://conal.net/papers/beautiful-differentiation/beautiful-differentiation-long.pdf) paper, the author says that differentiation is a "metafunction" that maps one function (e.g., $x^2$) to another ($2x$). On page two, he says

> For now, give differentiation the following higher order type:
>
> $d:: (a \rightarrow a) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow a)$

So far, it makes sense to me. Then he says the sum rule (i.e., for derivatives) is short hand for:

> $d(\lambda x \rightarrow u \ x + v\ x) \equiv \lambda x \rightarrow d \ u \ x  \ + \ d \ v \ x $

Where did $\lambda$ come from? What is the syntax of this thing trying to express?

The author continues by saying

> These more precise formulations are tedious...Fortunately, there is an
> alternative...The trick is to add numeric overloadings for functions,
> so that numeric operations apply point-wise. For instance,
>
> $u + v \equiv \lambda x \rightarrow u \ x + \ v \ x$

At this point, I no longer understand the expression at all. I would appreciate it if someone can explain the syntax and what the equivalence means.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the author is using a rather abstract language to talk about "functions" in an abstract way rather than "values of functions".

Many algebra and Calculus text make the distinction between "f", a function, and "f(x)", the numeric value when the function is applied to "x".

When he writes $d(\lambda x\rightarrow ux+ vx)$ he is saying that the derivative is being applied to the function $\lambda$ which, itself applied to variable x, is ux+ vx.  The last one, u+v≡λx→ ux+ vx, is again saying that "u+ v" is shorthand for the function, called $\lambda$, that takes the variable x to ux+ vx, in other words "u+v" is the function f(x)= (u+v)x.

Answer (score 1):

"Where did $\lambda$ come from ?" From the so-called **$\lambda$-calculus** which is a whole part of logic elaborated in the 1940s by Alonso Church, subsequently implemented as a (famous) programming language, LISP by Mc Carthy at MIT 20 years or so later. A gentle introduction can be found [here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/understanding-the-rules-of-lambda-calculus-for-functional-programming/).

I am very surprised that the author of the paper mentions "manifold-calculus" (refering to the great name of Spivak) without mentionning anywhere that in fact he uses $\lambda$-calculus. This author has in fact rediscovered things that exist for a long time. Not a good point. See the Wikipedia article [**Automatic Differentiation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) about this whole and well developed subject.